# Python Datareader cannot extract stock data from Morningstar

Tags: python, pandas, symbols, datareader, stock

I'm a beginner in python working with stock data. This morning I was able to extract stock data from the morningstar website fine, however when I try to do so now I receive the following error message shown below. What could be causing this issue and what can I do to fix it? Thanks

```
Exception Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
63 '''
64
---> 65 df=web.DataReader('MMM','morningstar', start, end)
66 print(df)
67 stockname=df.to_csv('mmm.csv')

~\Documents\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, access_key)
389 return MorningstarDailyReader(symbols=name, start=start, end=end,
390 retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause,
--> 391 session=session, interval="d").read()
392 elif data_source == 'robinhood':
393 return RobinhoodHistoricalReader(symbols=name, start=start, end=end,

~\Documents\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py in read(self)
217 "type %s" % type(self.symbols))
218
--> 219 df = self._dl_mult_symbols(symbols=symbols)
220 if len(df.index.levels[0]) == 0:
221 raise ValueError("None of the provided symbols were valid")

~\Documents\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py in _dl_mult_symbols(self, symbols)
128 else:
129 raise Exception("Request Error!: %s : %s" % (
--> 130 resp.status_code, resp.reason))
131
132 time.sleep(self.pause)

Exception: Request Error!: 404 : Not Found
```

Comment: You got a 404 which means the website you are requesting isn't there. Without seeing your code, it'd be very difficult to answer more.

Comment: Having same issue as reported [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/557).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a provider issue. The API isn't documented (I believe it came from [here](https://gist.github.com/hahnicity/45323026693cdde6a116)), so it's difficult to tell with certainty what changes were made / if it was taken down.

For now, I would recommend using other sources such as AlphaVantage, Quandl, or IEX. The simplest is IEX, which does not require an API key

`df = web.DataReader('MMM', 'IEX', start, end)`